"Unable to Transfer Data from Google BigQuery to Amazon S3 Without Using AWS Connectors (Glue/Appflow)"
I am trying to transfer data from Google BigQuery (GBQ) to Amazon S3 without using AWS connectors such as Glue or Appflow. When attempting to set up the data transfer, I can select S3 as a source, but it doesn't appear as a destination option.
I have attached screenshots showing the issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem or know how to configure a direct data transfer from GBQ to S3 without using any AWS-specific services?
In Source we are getting S3 and Many 
In destination we are getting no other options 
